# Vue2 + laravel6 - Component implementation

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-6

I just started using Vue2 with Laravel6 and got stuck when trying to understand how to use component method.

As I am totally new for Vue, I am using the official tutorial of Vue as a reference. What I learned from here(https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html) about Vue component instantiation is we give options to a component.(e.g. we give 'template:' options for HTML part.)

When I look at laravel6 codes of `resouces/js/app.js`, it looks something like this:

```
Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);
```

I looked at `js/components/ExampleComponent.vue` expecting to see some options declared there. However, there's no option in the ExampleComponent.vue file. Instead, I see `<template></template>` tag. Apparently, the `<template></template>` tag seems to work as 'template:' option.

I have two questions regarding above:

1. Does `<template></template>` tag have the same meaning as 'template:' option?
2. If question 1 is yes, are other options also replacable with corresponding tags? (e.g. Can I use `<props></props>` tag for 'props:' option? or `<data></data>` tag for 'data:' option?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Vue` world, there are two popular types of defining a `component`

### First Type

in this type, you add all of your `HTML` inside the `template` property
and the `props` add as `attribute` inside the `component` object to

```
Vue.component('button-counter', {
  data: function () {
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  },
  template: '<button v-on:click="count++">You clicked me {{ count }} times.</button>'
})
```

### Second Type

in this type you add your `component` logic in a separate file ends with `.vue`
for example in `laravel` there is an `ExampleComponent.vue` file you will find on
it just `template` tag just as a wrapper for your component content and your logic you can write it as it mentions below.

```
<template>
   // some content here
</template>

<script>
export default {
   props: [],
   methods: {
       
   },
   data(){
      return {
      }
   }
}
</script>
```

### Finally

there is no **tag** called `props` or `data`

for more info read this [article](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/03/24/vue-js-component-templates/)

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to know! Thank you so much for the perfect explanation!

Comment: @Umaru you are welcome :), please if it helped accept the answer